# Voting with Average of Probabilities in weka java code

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I would like to see the source code of Voting algorithm with average of probabilities. I know the weka repository but I can't find it.

Can anyone give me the link of the code??

Comment: Take a look [here](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/meta/Vote.java), method: distributionForInstanceAverage

Comment: Thankyou so much